# React change the Cursor pointer style on MUI Link

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I change the Cursor pointer style on MUI Link? It does not recognize style input below.

```
<Link
   style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
   onClick={() => {
     getTemplate();
   }}
</Link>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default cursor for Link is "pointer". You can try some other cursor and you should notice the difference.

```js
<Link
   style={{ cursor: 'crosshair' }}
   onClick={() => {
     getTemplate();
   }}
</Link>
```